# Dúvida ponteiro char C

Tags: c, ponteiro, char

Olá. Eu preciso fazer um ponteiro `char` apontar para uma posição de memória que guarda uma frase, em C.

Estou fazendo assim:

```
char *ptr;
char array[3] = {'o','l','a'};
ptr = &array;
```

Mas não entendo o que tem de errado, também não sei programar em C. Alguém pode ajudar? E não posso usar a biblioteca `string.h`.

Answer (score 4):

Em C/C++, o nome do array é um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento do array, então você pode fazer o seguinte:

```
ptr = array;
```

Outra coisa, se você quer guardar uma string num array de caracteres, não esqueça do terminador `'\0'`, senão podem acontecer coisas não esperadas.

```
char *ptr;
char array[] = {'o','l','a', '\0'};
char outroArray[] = "Ola"; // também funciona
ptr = array;
```

Comment: um adendo. Com isto, você pode utilizar essa nova variável como a ´array´, lembrando que você pode usar ptr[índice].
Para saber o tamanho to seu array, para uma futura consulta, você pode utilizar ´sizeof´, isso é: int tam = sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]), vai determinar o tamanho da sua array, no caso o tamanho total da array foi dividido pelo tamanho em bits de cada elemento da array, desta forma você pode saber o tamanho de um array de uma struct ou classe por exemplo.

Answer (score 3):

No seu trecho de código, array já é de um tipo compatível com ptr.

Então, o erro está na utilização do operador & na última linha.

Este operador pega o valor do endereço de memoria onde reside a variável array, que por si só é um ponteiro.

Em resumo, você está atribuindo o valor de um ponteiro de ponteiro de char para um ponteiro de char.
O que é semanticamente incorreto, mas o compilador não vai te avisar deste erro.

Para corrigir basta retirar o & assim:

```
ptr = array;
```

Outra observação: as strings em C devem ser terminadas com o caractere nulo '\0' que vale numericamente zero. Diversas funções o utilizam como marcador para sinalizar o final da string.

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
char *ptr = "Ola";
```